# JS decrement existing array values- NaN error

Tags: javascript, arrays, nan

I have some troubles with NaN values in my array. 
I can display that table, but after decrement opration(code at the bottom) when I want display actualized values I get all NaN. I don't have any idea how to fix that. I appreciate any help.

script.js

```
[![var result = "<table border=1>";
    for (var i = 0; i < wymiar; i++)
    {
        result += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < wymiar; j++)
        {
            tablica\[i, j\] = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);
            result += "<td>"+tablica\[i,j\]+"</td>";
        }
        result += "</tr>";
    }
    result += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("macierzLosowa").innerHTML = result;][1]][1]

var result1 = "<table border=1>";
    for (var i = 0; i < wymiar; i++)
    {
        result1 += "<tr>";
        for (var j = 0; j < wymiar; j++)
        {
            if (tablica[i, j] < minWWierszu[i])
            {
                minWWierszu[i] = tablica[i, j];
            }
        }
        for (var j = 0; j < wymiar; j++)
        {
            tablica[i, j] -= minWWierszu[i];
            result1 += "<td>"+tablica[i,j]+"</td>";
        }
        result1 += "</tr>";
    }
    result1 += "</table>";
    document.getElementById("NajmniejszeWiersz").innerHTML = result1;
```

index.html

```
<div id="NajmniejszeWiersz"></div>
```

[image]

Live example: https://jsfiddle.net/RadoszSzymon/aydr6bcm/2/

Comment: debug .........

Comment: Please provide a **runnable** [mcve].

Comment: I update my post with live example

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize the minWWierszu array with numeric values.
Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

There are several bugs in your code. The most important are:

1) JS has no support for multi-dimensional array in a way you are used to. The way to create a multi-dimensional array is to create an array of arrays. Also access to the cell of 2d array should be `tablica[i][j]` rather than `tablica[i, j]`. The wrong one works because `,` in many languages with C-inspired syntax is actually a valid operator returning its second argument. Thus `tablica[i, j]` is actually the same as `tablica[j]` rather than access to `(i, j)` cell of 2d-array

2) You initialize `minWKolumnie` two times (and don't use at all) but don't initialize values of `minWWierszu` that you actually use. The code should be

```js
var minWWierszu = new Array();
var minWKolumnie = new Array();
var tablica = new Array();

for (var i = 0; i < wymiar; i++)
{
    minWKolumnie[i] = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    minWWierszu[i] = Number.MAX_VALUE;
    tablica[i] = new Array();
}
```

Note that in JS you may (many do) use just `[]` instead of `new Array()` to create an empty array.

You also need to init (suprisingly unused) `jakas` 2d array in a similar way but as you create the variable much later I put it into the next loop:

```js
var jakas = new Array();
for (var i = 0; i < wymiar; i++)
{
    jakas[i] = new Array();
    for (var j = 0; j < wymiar; j++)
    {
        jakas[i][j] = tablica[i][j];
    }
}
```

After you fix that, code seems to work, look at the [updated JS fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xk58z01L/2/)